# Allow only ceratin characters in input message in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm quite new to python. My problem is that I have an input message let's say `Some sentence.`. However, the input characters are restricted to certain characters (both normal and accented letters, and special characters like `.,?!)`. I was trying to solve this problem with regex but my code doesn't work as intended.

```py
import re
    
message = input("Enter the message: \n")
p = re.compile('[ a-zA-Z.,?!]+', re.UNICODE)
if not p.search(message):
    print ("Not allowed characters")
else:
    print ("Allowed characters")
```

The problem with it is that it doesn't recognize the unallowed characters if the input has allowed ones. For example: `Some sentence` is a good input and the code works fine, however, with a sentence like this `Some sentence@<>`, the program won't recognize `@<>` characters as not allowed ones. However, if I only write "@<>", the code works as intended.

Is regex not the way to solve this problem?

Comment: `if not p.fullmatch(message):`

Comment: Now it seems to be working, but I'm having problems with accented letters. Any idea why? It returns "None" for them, so it doesn't find them?

Comment: I switched back to search and it doesn't work with that either. How is it possible? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: `a-zA-Z` matches ASCII letters only. Do you mean you want to match a string like `Виктор`?

Comment: I want to match ÁáÉéÓó etc. Is it possible?

Comment: I just realized it wasn't good with accented letters at the first place. Sorry for that. I had the same issue as I had with special characters, it didn't recognize the accented letters if it had ASCII letters next to them. So how should I change the code to fit accented letters like Áá?

Comment: Try `p = re.compile(r'(?:[^\W\d_]|[ .,?!])+')` and then `p.fullmatch`

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, it's working now as it should!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex like `(?:[^\W\d_]|[ .,?!])+` and the [`Pattern.fullmatch()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.fullmatch) to test if the *entire* string matches the pattern:

```py
import re
message = input("Enter the message: \n")
p = re.compile(r'(?:[^\W\d_]|[ .,?!])+')
if not p.fullmatch(message):
    print ("Not allowed characters")
else:
    print ("Allowed characters")
```

The regex means:

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `[^\W\d_]` - match any Unicode letter
  - `|` - or
  - `[ .,?!]` - a space, `.`, `,`, `?` or `!`
- `)+` - one or more times.